Outlook integration
We’d like to start using CiviCRM as part of our IMPACT CRM setup and need it to integrate with Outlook. Specifically, we’re looking for a solution where all new contacts added in Outlook are automatically synced with CiviCRM.
I noticed there’s an existing API available for this purpose. Could you provide some guidance on the simplest way to proceed with the integration?
Thank you for your support and assistance.
Best regards,
-Y.

Welcome Youcef. There are (at least) two extensions that you can consider:
Outlook 365 Integration
Outlook CiviCRM Integration
You can find documentation for both of them - so maybe you try them out and let us know if you encounter any problems?
